# How to hide a directory and its contents on CentOS when running “tree?”

Tags: command-line, centos-6, tree

I need to hide a directory on CentOS 6 when using `tree`. I want to do that because I'm running the `tree` command to print the tree directory structure, but I don't want see a particular directory in my tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tree can be told to ignore a folder like so

```
tree -I FOLDERNAME
```

Comment: You can also use wildcards here e.g. ./tmp/